# How do I access stroke color and width of a simple marker with python in QGIS?

Tags: python, qgis-3, style, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to set up style properties of a vector layer using python. I was able to modify the marker properties but I cannot modify those of Simple Marker, like width or color. 
Here is my code :

```
  layer=iface.activeLayer()

  # Marker

  single_symbol_renderer=layer.renderer()
  symbol=single_symbol_renderer.symbol()
  symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255,255,1))
  symbol.setSize(4)

  # Simple Marker

  marker_symb = QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayer()
  marker_symb.setStrokeColor(QColor(255,255,1))
  marker_symb.setStrokeWidth(0.9)
  layer.subSymbol(marker_symb)
  layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Please can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a similar method for the marker but by adding `symbol.symbolLayer(0)` to identify the initial simple marker layer:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
single_symbol_renderer = layer.renderer()
symbol = single_symbol_renderer.symbol()
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeColor(QColor(255,255,1))
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeWidth(0.9)

layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Comment: Thanks you so much ! Was tkinking about a solution for several days !

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind. It's about placement of labels. I would like to place them with "Offset from point" and define OffsetX and Offset Y. I tkink you have to use QgsPalLayerSettings but, in spite of my researches, i don't have find the solution to do it.

Comment: @ValentinL. - Most welcome! Glad it helped :). I suggest you ask this as a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). This would make it easier for people with similar problems to find a possible solution.