# Setting a Background Color with RVBT field with python

Tags: labeling, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, python-3

I'm trying to set the color of a background of a layer. To do this i created an attribute "Color" with the RVBT numbers associate to each feature. As in the picture, i want to set the color with those features to set differents color, but i don't know how to do this with python.

Here is an image :

[image]

Here is my code (I set red color for example) :

```
background_color = QgsTextBackgroundSettings()
background_color.setFillColor(QColor('red'))
background_color.setEnabled(True)  
layer_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
text_format = QgsTextFormat()
text_format.setFont(QFont("MS Shell Dlg 2"))
text_format.setSize(12.5)
text_format.setColor(QColor("black"))
text_format.setFont(QFont("MS Shell Dlg 2",11,QFont.Bold))
text_format.setBackground(background_color)
layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)
layer_settings.fieldName = "Valeur"
layer_settings.enabled = True
layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(layer_settings)
layer.triggerRepaint()
qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [QgsProperty()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProperty.html) and [QgsPropertyCollection()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPropertyCollection.html) classes to set the data defined properties. The enum property value `58` is for the background colour ([see here for a list of data definable properties](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/3bd3aba25b60f32c2170e519a5e9b37249d49be2/src/core/qgspallabeling.h#L323)):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

background_color = QgsTextBackgroundSettings()
background_color.setEnabled(True)

# Set up the data-defined properties
prop = QgsProperty()
prop.setField("Couleur")
pc = QgsPropertyCollection('ShapeFillColor')
pc.setProperty(58, prop)
layer_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
layer_settings.setDataDefinedProperties(pc)

text_format = QgsTextFormat()
text_format.setFont(QFont("MS Shell Dlg 2"))
text_format.setSize(12.5)
text_format.setColor(QColor("black"))
text_format.setFont(QFont("MS Shell Dlg 2",11,QFont.Bold))
text_format.setBackground(background_color)
layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)
layer_settings.fieldName = "Valeur"
layer_settings.enabled = True
layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(layer_settings)
layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: @ValentinL. - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)

Comment: Do you know the enum property for "Fill Color" of a Simple Marker from Single symbol property ?

Comment: @ValentinL. - It's `3`. It's supposed to be mentioned [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/607664c5a6b47c559ed39892e736322b64b3faa4/src/core/symbology/qgssymbollayer.h#L130) but I guess they forgot to update it :)

Comment: I'm so sorry but I don't understand how to set up the property of a layer like this (Fill color 3) with the layer. I tried the same thing that you did on your answer but it doesnt work ? I guess it's with QgsVectorLayer(), not sure..

Comment: @ValentinL. - No need to apologise. The code you use is similar to [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324889/how-do-i-access-stroke-color-and-width-of-a-simple-marker-with-python-in-qgis/324993#324993) and using the code to set the data-defined properties from this post above (excluding all label-related code). If you still need help, I would suggest you [ask a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: How it is getting different color for each value???? If anyone can explain that it would be so great. Is there any field or something which passes values according to which colors are displayed?

Comment: @ChetanVashisth - Yes, the "Couleur" field in this example is a string field which contains **rgba** values in a list. (e.g. `[48,111,65,79]`).

Comment: Thank you so much @Joseph.